# How to convert string value (ex: double value) to percentage in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Elegant workaround for JavaScript floating point number problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem)

I would like to know how we can convert the following value to a percentage in javascript?

First Expected Output

```
 Input Value   :  0.03222772304422584
 Expected Value:  0.03
```

Second Expected Output

```
 Input Value   :  0.03222772304422584
 Expected Value:  .03
```

Thanks in advance,

Kathir

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem), or search Stack Overflow for "floating point" "rounding" "javascript" (http://www.google.com/?q=site:stackoverflow.com%20floating%20point%20javascript%20rounding). It's a very common problem.

Comment: This one maybe work - Math.round (0.322277230442254 * 100) / 100

Comment: *"First...Expected Value: 0.03 / Second...Expected Value: .03"* Okay, what governs whether there should be a leading 0?

Comment: What do you mean by "*percentage*"? Both your numbers would be *3%*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) and [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) like:

```
var n = +"0.0322277230442258"; //converts String to Number
var r = n.toFixed(2); // returns 0.03

var r2 = r.slice(1): // returns .03 by removing the first character
```

Comment: OP operates on a string value, you forgot type conversion.

Comment: @jAndy I'm really good at not seeing things, but where does it state that it's a String value?

Comment: question title itself... those, mega bold letters :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
var val = "0.03222772304422584";

(+val).toPrecision(1);  // 0.03
(+val).toPrecision(1).slice(1);  // .03
```

ref.: [MDN .toPrecision()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision)